# Accessing IBOutlet of a controller in another class in COCOA

Tags: cocoa, iboutlet, nstablerowview

I have a controller with a IBOutlet as follow :

```
@interface MyController : NSViewController <NSPopoverDelegate>
{
    IBOutlet NSWindow *detachedWindow;
}
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSWindow *detachedWindow;
@end
```

I want to access that outlet(`detachedWindow`) in a class that is: This subclass is added for a cell view in view based table view.

```
    @interface HoverTableRowView : NSTableRowView<NSTableViewDelegate,NSPopoverDelegate>   {
     __weak MyController *_delegateObject;
}

@implementation HoverTableRowView
@synthesize delegateObject = _delegateObject;
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    NSLog(@"awake from nib is being called");
  NSLog(@"detached window outlet is--%@",[[self delegateObject ]detachedWindow]);

}
@end
```

But `detached window outlet is--` is always returning `null`. How can I access that outlet in `HoverTableRowView' class ?

Comment: Your code looks weird.. Are you trying to make xib of a NSViewController to be the view of a Cell? A cell that is located in a NSTableView of another Xib.. ?

Comment: I have only one xib of NSViewController. In that xib i have a NSTableView, that is view based. And I have subclassed NSTableRowView for adding a custom cell view related to my table view.

Comment: Were you able to resolve this?

Comment: no..i could not able to access.